# config.inc directly opening in a browse window . How to avoid that

Tags: php

we have a config.inc file in our website, that directly opening in the browser window. It has some credentials written in that config.inc file. how to avoid that opening from the browser.

```
eg. www.example.com/config/config.inc
output
<?php 

some credentials

?>
```

any sugesstions

Comment: change permission of that file

Comment: you could use config.inc.php , add .php extension at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Put it outside of your web root (**RECOMMENDED**)

2.Use htaccess to block .inc files

```
<Files ~ "\.inc$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

3.Put a quick check at the top of the file that checks for a variable. If that variable isn't set then you know it is being pulled up directly and should exit immediately:

```
<?if(!defined('IN_SCRIPT')){header('HTTP/1.0 404 not found');exit;}?>
```

4.Add a `php` extension to the file name so it is parsed as PHP or tell Apache to parse .inc files as PHP

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .inc
```

Answer (score 1):

Either add .php to the extension, or create a `.htaccess` file in your webroot directory with this in it (Assuming you are using Apache of course):

```
<Files ~ "\.inc$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```